# Will voodoo demon drop the voodoo doll every kill?

Tags: terraria-mobile

Before I go into the underworld to get the guide voodoo doll, I want to know if the voodoo demon will drop the guide voodoo doll every time. Is there a way to increase my chance so if it doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

The drop rate for the Guide Voodoo Doll from [Voodoo Demons](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Voodoo_Demon) is listed on the official wiki as 100%, so no, there's no way to increase the drop rate as it's guaranteed to drop already. Note that it doesn't drop *at all* from regular demons, and there's no way to make them drop it.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the help! I prefer sites other than the wiki because on my iPad it glitches out so that I can't read text.

Answer (score -4):

It depends on what weapon you are using.  If you were using a wooden sword, there would be a low chance of dropping the doll, but if you are using a Knightsedge or an Excalibur it would be quite common.

Comment: Now, I am not familiar with mobile, so maybe it does things differently, although the wiki doesn't mention it, but in the PC version, and as described in the wiki, the doll will always drop from a voodoo demon, and never from a regular demon.

Comment: @Nick that is also my understanding of it as well. The official wiki lists [Voodoo Demons](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Voodoo_Demon) as having a 100% drop rate on the Guide Voodoo Doll, whereas regular [Demons](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demon) don't list it as a drop at all. I'm downvoting this because it's factually incorrect - the weapon you use has no impact on the drops, the drop rate is fixed at 100%.

Comment: Weapons of choice dont impact drop rates.

Comment: Please cite a source for you conjecture.  I have never heard of weapon choice affecting drop rate.